# Windows services wrapper на java

Tags: java, windows-service

Нужны java методы для работы с сервисами на винде: получить по имени, start,stop, переконфигурирование.

Искал какие-нибудь библиотеки или врапперы - ничего не нашел.
Все запросы про org.tanukisoftware.wrapper (помогает java-приложение установить, как сервис).

Может вы подскажете какие нибудь механизмы?

p.s. через Runtime не хочу делать

Comment: JNI, JNA не годятся?

Comment: @Sergey не хотелось бы юзать это

Comment: А как иначе представляете доступ к специфическим функциям из в целом платформенно-независимой  жавы?

Comment: @Sergey поэтому и спрашиваю, может что-то уже готовое есть

Comment: В jna представлены многие функции winapi. даже из kernel